# Strip_tags and php

Tags: php

I've this variable in php:

```
 image/svg+xml,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="62" height="57"><path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 13 5 c -0.02 0.1 -0.39 4.17 -1 6 c -0.67 2.02 -2.57 3.96 -3 6 c -1.15 5.51 -0.64 12.54 -2 18 c -0.84 3.37 -3.95 6.69 -5 10 c -0.85 2.68 -1 9 -1 9"/><path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 9 29 c 0.09 0 3.62 0.34 5 0 c 1 -0.25 1.99 -1.84 3 -2 c 2.81 -0.43 10 0 10 0"/><path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 29 5 c 0.07 0.21 3.63 8.04 4 12 c 0.9 9.7 0.52 22.2 0 31 c -0.06 1.02 -2 3 -2 3"/><path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 59 1 c 0 0.82 -0.53 33.64 0 47 c 0.04 1.02 1.75 2 2 3 c 0.34 1.38 0 5 0 5"/></svg>
```

I need to strip tag SVG to obtain this string:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="62" height="57"><path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 13 5 c -0.02 0.1 -0.39 4.17 -1 6 c -0.67 2.02 -2.57 3.96 -3 6 c -1.15 5.51 -0.64 12.54 -2 18 c -0.84 3.37 -3.95 6.69 -5 10 c -0.85 2.68 -1 9 -1 9"/><path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 9 29 c 0.09 0 3.62 0.34 5 0 c 1 -0.25 1.99 -1.84 3 -2 c 2.81 -0.43 10 0 10 0"/><path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 29 5 c 0.07 0.21 3.63 8.04 4 12 c 0.9 9.7 0.52 22.2 0 31 c -0.06 1.02 -2 3 -2 3"/><path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 59 1 c 0 0.82 -0.53 33.64 0 47 c 0.04 1.02 1.75 2 2 3 c 0.34 1.38 0 5 0 5"/></svg>
```

But using `strip_tags($string, '<svg>');`
I get this (but it is not good):

```
image/svg+xml,< svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="379" height="64"></svg>
```

Comment: You could probably strip off the `image/svg+xml,` from the front with a regex or `str_replace()` then use a `DOMDocument` class to get what you want: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to extract the `svg` element:

```
preg_match('/(<svg.+<\/svg>)/im', $string, $match);
echo $match[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can strip the unwanted part of text using the [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function as follows:

```
<?php

$text = 'image/svg ... </svg>'; // full data
$text = preg_replace('/image\/.*\.dtd">/im', '', $text);

echo $text;

?>
```

Visit [this link](https://eval.in/928907) to see the script in action.